# How to replace a pattern using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Before anything, I've googled this question, and I found the solution (apparently). But I can't make it work. So my question is more *"Why is this wrong..."* more than *"How to make this..."*

I wrote this code:

```
private const string pattern = @"^[_L]{2}[0-9]{2}$";
public string RemoveL(string child)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    return regex.Replace("SUB_1_SC_0310_1_A_L01", "");
}
```

This code tries to remove `L_XX` from any string. So:

> SUB_1_SC_0310_1_A_L01  --> SUB_1_SC_0310_1_A

But it returns the same string `SUB_1_SC_0310_1_A_L01`.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to remove everything after the last underscore (including)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong because you used `^$` which means start & end of string. Change your regex to `[_L]{2}[0-9]{2}` and it will works.

Note that you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` and `[_L]{2}` will match any combination of `_` and `L`, prefer `_L` instead.

I would use `_L\d{2}`.

It seems that you want to make the second digit optional. You have a few options:

- `_L\d\d?` <= The `?` make the second digit optional;
- `_L\d{1,2}` <= `{a,b}` ensure that the previous pattern is present from `a` to `b` times (inclusive)

Comment: `[_L]{2}` will match: `LL` `L_` and `__` aswell.

Comment: @lbarros I know but I didn't have the time to write it down ;)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Ok ;)

Comment: How to make it detect _L01 or _L1 with a maximum of 2 digits?

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm ^^

Answer (score 1):

The right pattern is

```
    private const string pattern = @"_L[0-9]{2}$";
```

Notice absence of `^` (string has no need to *start* with `[_L]`) and `{2}` after `_L` (you want just `"_L"`, not any of {_, L} set twice).

Explanation:

```
   _L       - exactly _L
   [0-9]{2} - exactly 2 digits 0..9  
   $        - end of string
```

If you want to replace `"xxxxL_01"` (please, notice `L` and `_` order) as well then

```
    private const string pattern = @"[_L]{2}[0-9]{2}$";
```

Explanation:

```
   _L       - '_' and 'L' in any order (i.e. either _L or L_)
   [0-9]{2} - exactly 2 digits 0..9  
   $        - end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your pattern are the characters '^' and '$' which say match the beginning and the end of the string. If you remove them, your pattern will match the string _L01, for instance, anywhere in the string.

so your pattern should be

```
private const string pattern = @"[_L]{2}[0-9]{2}";
```

Besides if you use `[_L]` it means one element of the class composed of the characters `'_'` and `'L'`. It will match `"_L"` but also `"__"`, `"L_"`, or `"LL"`. 
If you want to be more restrictive and match only "_L" your pattern should be

```
private const string pattern = @"_L[0-9]{2}";
```